# Integral of $(\sec x\tan x)^2$

Tags: integration

I came across this problem in a textbook:

> Find the volume of the solid generated by revolving the region in the first quadrant bounded above by the line
> $y=\sqrt 2$, below by the curve $y=\sec x \tan x$, and on the left by the $y$-axis, about the line $y=\sqrt 2$.

I did succeed in finding the intersection point as $x=π/4$. Since the axis of rotation is $y=\sqrt 2$, the function defining the radius of the disk (in the disk method) is $(\sec x\tan x-\sqrt 2)^2$.
Hence the area function of the rotating body is: $A= π \int_0^{π/4} (\sec x\tan x-\sqrt 2)^2 \, dx$. Upon expanding the terms, I got $A= π \int_0^{π/4} (\sec^2x\tan^2x + 2\sqrt{2}\sec x\tan x+ 2)\, dx$.
I could integrate the last two terms but not the first one, $\int \sec^2 x\tan^2x\, dx$.

Comment: It is $\frac 1 3 (\tan x)^{3}$+C.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If you see an integral $\int \tan^n(x) \sec^2(x) dx$, substitute $u=\tan(x)$.